# Connected to an IPv4 port by IPv6 on Mac OS X 10.14.4

Tags: networking, macos, ipv6, localhost

I have a default `/etc/hosts` which resolve localhost to IPv4 and IPv6 as normal on my Mac OS X 10.14.4.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Then, I use netcat to bind a port on IPv4 only and try to connect to it by localhost.

```
> sudo nc -4l 80
```

```
> netstat -an | grep LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN
```

I try to connect to localhost.

I suppose that the first trial of localhost using IPv6 will be rejected because there are no programs binding to IPv6 port 80, like

```
> telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

However, on my Mac OS X 10.14.4, it is

```
> telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It connects in success but the connection is dropped right after.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's not limited to ipv4. Add -4 to do that.

Comment: @davidbaumann
Thank you David.

It seems that OSX's netcat works differently from the man page. -4 and -6 are supposed to limit to IPv4 or IPv6 respectively. However, when I use `nc -l` or `nc -4l`, it listens to IPv4 only while it listens to IPv4 and IPv6 if I use `nc -6l`. So strange.

Anyway, I can still connect to the port by IPv6 even I used `nc -4l`.
Still investigating the reason.

Comment: Which netcat does macOS have? The original BSD netcat is kind of buggy and hasn't been maintained since 2007. Worse, there's a GNU rewrite of netcat, which hasn't been maintained since 2004! and appears to be what is in homebrew. What a mess. There's a currently maintained rewrite of netcat by the nmap developers, which is what I use on Linux. I can't find it in homebrew.